# ActiveAdmin throws error when posting comment to a nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

Using the awesome ActiveAdmin gem I've run into an issue with comments.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Sale do
  belongs_to :channel

  show do |sale|
    # stuff to show sale resource...

    # allow comments on sales
    active_admin_comments
  end
end
```

If I post a comment to a sale with the above setup, the comment posts, but then crashes on the redirect with:

```
undefined method `admin_sale_path' for #<Admin::CommentsController:0x007ffed79bb210>
```

The correct routing method would be `admin_channel_sale_path(sale.channel, sale)` but it does not seem to be able to figure that out, and I'm not sure where to patch this up.

Is there is a place in my `Sale` resource where I can override the routing method used to prevent this error?

Comment: can you reveal your Comment resource ?

Comment: It's ActiveAdmin's Comment resource.  I don't have any files for it in my app.

Comment: Have you tried using the latest code on Github?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Derp... This was actually fixed when I upgraded to 0.6.0 to 0.6.2.  Move along... :(

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you `channel` is coped to the `sale`

In routes.rb

```
namespace "sale" do
  namespace "namespace" do
    resources :channel
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it related to this? https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/2082

They have a pull request open, it has not been merged.